# Scrapy after login parsing the url list

Tags: python, scrapy

I am not very familiar with python so please have patience with me.
I have a scrapy crawler, that works like it should, but now I need to do a new one, but this time it should crawl a logged in session.
So my scrapy uses as start_urls a list of urls obtained from a sitemap, it should make a request to the login form, then, if logged in it should start parsing my list...

This is my code so far :

```
class StockPricesSpider(Spider):
    name = "logged-in"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    d = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime())
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/customer/account/login/']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'myuser', 'password': 'mypass'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "Invalid login or password." in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return
        else:
             logging.log(logging.INFO,'Logged in and start parsing')
             return Request("http://www.example.com/", callback=self.parse_products)

    def parse_products(self, response):
        f = open("data/sitemaps/urls04102015.txt")
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        f.close()
        d = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime())
        if os.path.exists("data/results/stock_"+d+".csv"):
            os.remove("data/results/stock_"+d+".csv")             

        sel = Selector(response)
        separator = ";"
        items = []

        item = MyPrices()
        sku = sel.xpath('.//strong[@itemprop="productID"]/text()').extract()
        logging.log(logging.INFO, sku)
        if len(sku) > 0:        
            item['sku'] = "med_" + sel.xpath('.//strong[@itemprop="productID"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            ...
        items.append(item)         
        return items
```

So this is not working, because I am not calling the parser correctly.
So basically, I do not get errors, but the urls do not get parsed either.
So the login works, I succeed logging in, but after that (after login) how do I do what scrapy does (parsing the list of urls) ?

**EDIT**
I found a new approach to my problem, but it also does not work properly. Please help me debug this (or the first approach)

```
class StockPricesSpiderX(InitSpider):
    name = "logged-in"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    login_page = 'https://www.example.com/ro/customer/account/login/' 
    d = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime())
    f = open("data/sitemaps/urls04102015.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()
    if os.path.exists("data/results/stock_"+d+".csv"):
        os.remove("data/results/stock_"+d+".csv")

    def init_request(self):
        """ Called before crawler starts """
        logging.log(logging.INFO, 'before crawler starts...')
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        """ Generate login request """
        logging.log(logging.INFO, 'do login...')
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'name':'myuser','password':'mypass'},
                                         callback=self.check_login_response)
    def check_login_response(self,response):
        """ Check the response returned by login request to see if we are logged in """
        if "Invalid login or password." in response.body:
            logging.log(logging.INFO,'... BAD LOGIN ...')
        else:
            logging.log(logging.INFO, 'GOOD LOGIN... initialize')
            self.initialized()

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        separator = ";"
        items = []
        item = StockPrices()
        sku = sel.xpath('.//strong[@itemprop="productID"]/text()').extract()
        logging.log(logging.INFO, sku)
        ...
        items.append(item)         
        return items
```

The log of the execution shows this:

```
2015-12-03 14:54:16 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-12-03 14:54:16 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-12-03 14:54:16 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'products.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'calinxautomat.csv', 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['products.spiders'], 'DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS': 'products.items.Subcategories', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
2015-12-03 14:54:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-12-03 14:54:23 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-12-03 14:54:23 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-12-03 14:54:23 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: myWriteToCsv
2015-12-03 14:54:23 [root] INFO: before crawler starts...
2015-12-03 14:54:23 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-12-03 14:54:24 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-12-03 14:54:25 [root] INFO: do login...
2015-12-03 14:54:26 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-12-03 14:54:26 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

...

So this one does not seem to get passed the login phase... It's like the callback does not exit from formRequest...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `parse_products()` the assignment to `start_urls` will be using a variable local to that routine, not the class global you set up at the top of your spider. In any event I don't think that assigning to start_urls will do what you want, scrapy wont notice and then parse them. What you need to do is queue the new urls to be parsed.

```
for url in f.readlines()
    yield Request(url.strip(), callback=self.parse_products)
```

Update: from your update: scrapy has a url filter so it doesn't revisit pages. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928253/why-is-my-scrapy-spider-not-following-the-request-callback-in-my-item-parse-func/), tldr: set `dont_filter=True` in the FormRequest

Comment: I get the list of URLs using that code. I am sure of it.  I will try your suggestions and come back to you. I also found a new approach, so please check out the question for my EDIT and let me know what you think...